# How to find the residues of this function at $x=2ni\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How would you find residues of:

$$\frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}$$

At $x=2ni\pi$

Comment: $(x-2\pi i ) \frac{ (-x)^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1} $ and take the limit of this expression at the point $ x \to 2\pi i 4

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}$.  We see that $f$ has simple poles at $z=i2n\pi$ and a branch point at $z=0$.  To find the residues for $n\ne 0$ we write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to i2n\pi}(z-i2n\pi)f(z)&=\lim_{z\to i2n\pi}\frac{(z-i2n\pi)(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to i2n\pi} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z}\\\\
&=(-i2n\pi)^{s-1}\\\\
&=e^{(s-1)\log(-i2n\pi)}
\end{align}$$

In order to evaluate the residues further, we would need to cut the plane and select a branch of the complex logarithm.

Comment: Thanks, how do you get from the first line to the second?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark